# Partial Fraction Decomposition $\frac{2x^2+3x+3}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}$

Tags: calculus

How would one go about decomposing this fraction?

$$ 
2x^2+3x+3\over
(x+1)(x^2+1)
$$

Here is what I have so far:
$$
{2x^2+3x+3\over
(x+1)(x^2+1)
} =
 { A\over x+1 } + { Bx+C\over x^2+1} $$

$$
{2x^2+3x+3\over
(x+1)(x^2+1)
} =
 { A(x^2+1) } + (Bx+C)(x+1) $$

I know how to solve for A - it's 1. But how do I get B and C?

Comment: After multiplying throughout with the denominator, why is it still there in the LHS?

Comment: Just equate the corresponding coefficients on both sides, you will get 3 simple equations to solve.

Comment: Oops! You're right @Maccavity it should not be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have
$2x^2 + 3x + 3 = A(x^2+1) + (Bx+C)(x+1)$

Now, try suitable values of $x$ to find $A, B, C$.  For e.g. $x = -1$ will easily give you $A$.  Hint, there is another value which easily gives you $C$ after you know $A$.

In case no suitable $x$ values occur to you, just use a few simple values to get as many equations as the coefficients, and then solve a set of linear equations.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
2x^2 + 3x +3 &= A(x^2 + 1) + (Bx+C)(x+1)\\
&= x^2(A+B) + x(B+C) + A+C
\end{align}
$$

By comparing the corresponding co-efficients  :
$$
A+B = 2;\\
B+C = 3;\\
C+A = 3;
$$

By solving, $A = 1$, $B = 1$, $C = 2$.